# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia 740m and hd400 no screen detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics

i tried every possible way that i found on google to install nvidia drvier with bumblebee and without and every version of the driver and i end up after booting with a black screen and a cursor witch does not blink. when i uninstall all stuff related to nvidia everything is working but on intel hd4000

xorg log say screen not found .

lspci :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
```

ubuntu-drivers devices

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
model    : GK107M [GeForce GT 740M]
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000FDFsv00001043sd00001477bc03sc02i00
driver   : nvidia-340 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

nvidia-xconfig

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

when i run nvidia-settings everyting is empty because its not detecting driver/card, when i reboot it can not log in to do any change.

bumblebee return that there is no driver.
nvidia-prime same with no bumblebee

every option from ubuntu-drivers devices do the same as manual install with apt-get.

Comment: What method did you use to install the driver? Did you use nvidia-xconfig?

Comment: @GearyShull  i updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete everything related to nvidia
   sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
2. Upgrade your linux kernel to 3.16
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
3. Delete old kernels 
   dpkg --list | grep linux-image
   sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic { do it carefully don't remove latest}

Now restart, then is terminal, run `sudo apt-get autoremove`

1. Install intel graphics driver {will take some time }
   https://01.org/linuxgraphics/
2. After Intel drivers are installed system will restart.
3. Go to system setting > software & update > additional drivers.
4. Click on nvidia proprietary driver ( my case its nvidia-331 )
   do not use apt-get in terminal for this
5. Click Apply changes, it will take some time as drivers will be downloaded in background. [be patient] when finished, restart ubuntu.
6. Now you will be using nvidia drivers.
7. If screen goes blank after restarting, ask me again, will give more detailed steps.